# passing array of strings to value attribute of input jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this input tag with **id="clientAdd"** when user write on it and click enter the written can be added in div as a tag and all tags are saved as array of strings I want to pass this array to the value of the hidden input tag id="clientAddCode"

```
<input type="text" id="clientAdd" value="" class="form-control required">
<input type="hidden" id="clientAddCode" name="address">
```

I try to pass the array of strings as it to the value of the hidden input tag id="clientAddCode" but it always gives me empty value.

```
var stringList = [];
$("#clientAdd").keypress(function (e) {
if (e.which === 13) {
     $(".target").append("<a href='#' class='tag'>" +"<span class='removeAddress'>"+'+'+"</span>"+ this.value + "</a>");
        stringList.push(this.value);
        this.value = "";
        $(document).on("click", ".removeAddress", function() {
            var removeItem = $(this).parent().clone().children().remove().end().text();
            stringList = $('.removeAddress').map(function(){
              return $(this).parent().clone().children().remove().end().text()
            }).get()
            $(this).parent().remove();
            $("#clientAddCode").val(stringList);
            console.log(stringList);
        });
     }
});
```

Comment: Please share all your relevant JS code so we can see where the problem is .

Comment: If you're trying to pass an array of strings to input, pass it as JSON string (using `JSON.stringify(your_array)` in input value). And when you fetch it, reverse parse it using `JSON.parse(your_json_string)`

Comment: @ Mihai T i edited it check plz

Comment: After `stringList.push(this.value);`, you are assigning the value `stringList = $('.removeAddress').map...` So the pushed values will be lost? Can you debug that?

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the array in a single string, you could do this using the [join](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) function:

> The **join()** method joins the elements of an array into a string, and returns the string.
>
> *array.join(separator)*
>
> separator *Optional*. The separator to be used. If omitted, the elements are separated with a comma

See following please:

```js
var arr = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
var stringList = arr.join(", ");
console.log(stringList);
//Write in a div
$("#clientAddCode").html(stringList);
//Write in a text
$("#myList").val(stringList);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clientAddCode"></div>
<input id="myList" type="text" />
```

In the above example, I've concatenated all the items with a comma.
I hope it helps you, bye.

Comment: thank u but my main problem is sending these values test1,test2,test3 to attribute value of input tag it always value empty

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking, anyway see my updated example please. To set the `value` attribute you should use the `.val()` method.